I want to change the current location blue marker color in flutter
I want to change the color of current location blue marker to orange color. However , I have changed the radius color. But, the blue dot color is not changing. Can, anyone please guide me how to change the current location blue marker ( dot ) to any other color?
So far I have tried, what I can do. But, nothing achieved. During my research I have found that "Google Maps Flutter doesn't provide direct customization of the default blue dot for the current location. However, you can overlay a colored circle on top of the current location marker."
Is it true? if no, can you please guide me?

Replace the default current location icon with a custom one.

You can customize your marker by using
Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId('marker_id'),
    position: LatLng(lat, lon),
    icon: //customize icon,
}

and add to your map like this
GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition = const CameraPosition(
    target: _kMapCenter,
    zoom: 7.0,
  ),
  markers = _markers,
  onMapCreated = _onMapCreated,
),

ref : https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/marker_icons.dart
